# Osclass Category Translation not showing front end

Tags: php, categories, translate, osclass

here my website i was installed osclass script.it need to be multilingual so, translated to local Sinhala (si_SI). categories were also updated with both Sinhalese and English language. but at the front end while switch into languages its categories were only shows on English only. was anyone had solution for showing categories also in other languages?

1. front end with Sinhala Language
   http://i60.tinypic.com/17cy9j.jpg "front end with Sinhala Language"
2. front end with English Language
   http://i59.tinypic.com/314s1u1.jpg "front end with English Language"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you echo the categories in the select element it probably needs to be translation ready. eg `<?php _e('categoryName', 'translationName');?>`

[Translating and editing language files Osclass](https://doc.osclass.org/Translating_and_editing_language_files_(.po_and_.mo))

Answer (score 2):

Osclass bug. They generate Bad SQL for the categories:

```
SELECT *
FROM ((SELECT a.*,  b.*,  c.i_num_items,  FIELD(fk_c_locale_code,  'sv_SE') as locale_order
FROM (oc_t_category as a)
INNER  JOIN oc_t_category_description as b ON a.pk_i_id = b.fk_i_category_id
LEFT  JOIN oc_t_category_stats  as c  ON a.pk_i_id = c.fk_i_category_id
WHERE b.s_name != ''
AND a.b_enabled = 1
ORDER BY locale_order DESC) dummytable)
GROUP BY pk_i_id
ORDER BY i_position ASC
```

This is SQL example for Sweden. The SQL itself orders rows by locale_order. Which is 1 - sv_SE and 0 - en_US. And simply tries to group by pk_i_id. On some mysql configurations it works, but on some not.

As stated in MySQL reference manual (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) values chosen by GROUP BY extension are indeterminate - it is not "guaranteed" that first row (top->down) with distinct value will be chosen in the final result.

**No solution provided in this post.**

Comment: I've made a pull request recently on this particular matter: https://github.com/osclass/Osclass/pull/2034. Hope it will be merged soon, though.